# android okhttp websocket switch network from 3G/LTE to WiFi or vice-versa

Tags: android, websocket, android-wifi, okhttp, lte

I am using a websocket in my android chat app. Socket reconnection fails when I switch from LTE to WiFi or vice-versa.

- Wifi -> Airplane mode ->Wifi   Works fine
- LTE -> Airplane mode ->Wifi   FAILS
- LTE -> Airplane mode ->LTE   Works fine
- Wifi -> Airplane mode ->LTE   FAILS

I am creating websocket using Okhttp. There is code around to detect Connectivity as WiFi or LTE, but that isn't the problem.

I read few posts some asking to put this below property, but that didn't work.
    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive","false");

I tried to clear cache as below, but that didnt work.
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .cacheControl(new  CacheControl.Builder().noCache().build())
                        .url(url)

None of the above worked.

The problem is to make the websocket realize that IP has changed and try using the new IP. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

never mind, this is our server guy's problem who was sending 400s because user changed their IP